# How to develop using Instagram API without smartphones

Tags: instagram

I want to develop an application which would query to instagram API. For this purpose I intend to create an instagram application (for my test environment). The only problem is that I do not have a smartphone. Is it possible to create an instagram app and generate some data for testing purpose without having a smartphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked somebody to give me a user. With that user I have logged in and created the instagram application. Then I could connect to it and use it.